# PHP: Change image in a div depending on what page is loaded?

Tags: php

I'm horrible at wording these questions but I hope that gives a good enough idea of what I'm trying to do.

I have 7 pages and 7 images, the images are all "waterfall_01.jpg", "waterfall_02.jpg", etc up to 7.

The code I have is simple so far:

```
    <?php 
        $cp = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        $cf = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    ?>
    <img src="/img/waterfall_0<?php if ($cp == "about.php" || $cf == "/about"){ echo "1"; }?>.jpg" />
```

How would I change this code to echo a different number between 1 and 7 based on 7 different pages (some of which have folders with some folders under them represented in a dropdown menu).

Technically I could just write a really long line:

```
    <img src="/img/waterfall_0<?php
        if ($cp == "home.php"){ echo "1"; }
        if ($cp == "about.php" || $cf == "/about"){ echo "2"; }
        if ($cp == "products.php" || $cf == "/products"){ echo "3"; }
        if ($cp == "services.php" || $cf == "/services"){ echo "4"; }
        if ($cp == "gallery.php" || $cf == "/gallery"){ echo "5"; }
        if ($cp == "faq.php"){ echo "6"; }
        if ($cp == "contact.php"){ echo "7"; }
    ?>.jpg" />
```

I'm not that great with PHP yet, I'm not sure if the above is the best or right way to do this so all help is appreciated!

The test server is http://www.mrobertsdesign.ca/home.php

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it not working at all ?

Comment: what you want to do will work, you might consider having an `else` statement in case there's an unexpected referring page. a `switch` statement might be more elegant, but won't actually do anything different

Comment: @TBI to be honest with you I didn't test that last part until now, thought of it as I was writing the question, it works fine... The website loads 3 times as fast now too instead of putting the html and the img tag in each page. I feel like this would be useful for many people.

Comment: @anthonygore Please tell me more! I don't really know how to write PHP very well, this was pretty much a mix of a few things I've had help with a while ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use if else

```
<?php
$cp = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$cf = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

if($cp == "home.php")
{
    $img_src = "1.jpg";
}
else if($cp == "about.php" || $cf == "/about"))
{
    $img_src = "2.jpg";
}
else if($cp == "products.php" || $cf == "/products")
{
    $img_src = "3.jpg";
}
else if($cp == "services.php" || $cf == "/services")
{
    $img_src = "4.jpg";
}
else if($cp == "gallery.php" || $cf == "/gallery")
{
    $img_src = "5.jpg";
}
else if($cp == "faq.php")
{
    $img_src = "6.jpg";
}
else if($cp == "contact.php")
{
    $img_src = "7.jpg";
}
?>
<img src="/img/waterfall_0<?php echo $img_src;?>" />
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you included the .jpg in the PHP? Thanks for this answer! I'm also assuming we don't need that second bracket after the About line haha

Comment: may be some of images in .png or .gif or some other so its quite simple to change their name as well extension.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

$requestedURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$images = array(
    "/home" => "1",
    "/about" => "2",
    "/products" => "3",
    "/services" => "4",
    "/gallery" => "5",
    "/faq" => "6",
    "/contact" => "7",
);

?>

<img src="/img/waterfall_0<?= $images[$requestedURI]; ?>.jpg"/>
```

Just make sure your URLs match the array keys.

Comment: if an unexpected referring page links to this it will cause an index out of bounds error. you need to first check if the array key exists. better of using an if/else or switch to avoid dealing with that

Comment: Those only seem to check for folders, not everything is in a specified folder, the main 7 pages in my case are in the root folder and then their subsequent pages are under said named folders. Great answer and thank you for your time =)

Answer (score 4):

Both answers by Justin Workman and Satish Sharma are workable solutions. But why not through in the other alternative. **Switch** statements.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch ($url) {
    case '/about':
    case '/about.php':
        $img = 2;
        break;
    case '/contact':
    case '/contact.php':
        $img = 3;
        break;
    ......
    default:
        $img = '1';
}
```

And then output the variable into your img tag.

Comment: This is a valid alternative and deserves a +1

Comment: This is very interesting! I've never seen anything like this before, nor do I really understand this haha

Comment: @mattroberts33 It is just like the if/else statement and the case has to equate to *true* before it is run. The only code that limits what value is set is the break. Basically the *case '':* and *break;* are the brackets *{}* for the if statement. Just allows for grouping of items. I use switches and if/else statements interchangeably in my coding.

Comment: @JamesWilliams I suppose I feel more comfortable with the if/else statements because I'm used to JS. This is really interesting though, is it better to use this compared to the other though??

Comment: @mattroberts33 Unfortunately there is no better way. You can search which has a better performance, and you will see results that go both ways. Ultimately they are roughly the same. JS also has switch statement and the structure is the same.

Comment: To add on what @JamesWilliams said, a switch is more efficient because you only pass one reference of the variable to the condition. Whereas You pass the variable every time you run an `if`.